# Javascript/Electron run script when url changed

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I try to make an electron app, but this script doesn't work. I really don't know what's wrong. Hopefully anyone can help me?

```
function search() {
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    const BrowserWindow = remote.BrowserWindow;
    var x = document.getElementById("searchText").value;
    var search = x.replace(/ /g, "+");
    var searchWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        frame: false
    });
    searchWindow.setPosition(100, 100);
    searchWindow.setMenu(null);
    searchWindow.loadURL("https://youtube.com/results?search_query=" + search);

    searchWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function() {
            var theUrl = url;
            var dWindow = new BrowserWindow({
                width: 800,
                height: 600,
                frame: false
            });
            dWindow.setPosition(200, 200);
            dWindow.setMenu(null);
            dWindow.loadURL(theUrl);
        }
    }
```

It doesn't even create the searchWindow (and also the dWindow).
When I remove this, the searchWindow does show up (but the dWindow does not):

```
searchWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function() {
            var theUrl = url;
            var dWindow = new BrowserWindow({
                width: 800,
                height: 600,
                frame: false
            });
            dWindow.setPosition(200, 200);
            dWindow.setMenu(null);
            dWindow.loadURL(theUrl);
        }
```

In my HTML code I have

```
<form action=>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." id="searchText" />
    <input type="button" value="Search.." onclick="search()" id="searchButton" />
    <script src="searchFunction/search.js" />
</form>
```

Comment: `dWindow.loadURL(url);` it seems url is undefined.

Comment: I changed it, but the searchWindow and the dWindows still do not show. When I remove the
    searchWindow.webContents.on('will-navigate', function() { ... }
It works. It doesn't matter what's inside the fuction, when I add this line of code, the searchWindow does show, but the dWindow (of couse) does not.

Comment: check https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/11885

Comment: From [docs](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#event-will-navigate):  
"This event will not emit when the navigation is started programmatically with APIs like webContents.loadURL", which you actually do. Give 'did-navigate' a shot (and I'd also define the listener before actually call loadURL)